# Список инициализации членов

Tags: c++, конструктор

Здравствуйте, интересует вопрос, возможно ли с помощью некоторой переменной mySpace, а также конструктора базового класса устанавливать величину из enum'а? Идея заключается в том, чтобы избавиться от параметра в функции foo.

```
namespace mySpace{
   enum myEnum {val1=0, val2, val3, fin}; 
      const char *setVal(int par){
      static const char *valNames[fin]={"this val1","this val2","this val3"}; 
        if(par>=0 && par <fin)return valNames[fin];
        return "error"; 
     }
}
class Parent {
    public:
      virtual void foo(int par)=0;     
};
class Child : public Parent{
    public:
      void foo(int par){
         char name[64];
         sprintf(name, "%s", mySpace::setVal(par));
      }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, создать поле для этого параметра и инициализировать его при создании объекта (передавать в конструктор):

```
#define NAME_LENGTH 64

namespace mySpace
{
    enum myEnum {
        val1=0,
        val2,
        val3,
        fin
    }; 

    const char* setVal( int par )
    {
        static const char* valNames[ fin ] = {
            "this val1", "this val2", "this val3"
        }; 

        if ( par >= 0 && par < fin )
            return valNames[ fin ];

        return "error"; 
    }
}

class Parent
{
    public:
        virtual void foo()=0;  
    private:
        int _par;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    public:
        Child( int parameter )
        {
            _par = parameter;
        }
        void foo()
        {
            char name[ NAME_LENGTH ];
            sprintf( name, "%s", mySpace::setVal( _par ) );
        }
};
```